# using cacheFactory in service for CRUD

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I want to create a prototype for an application and I don't want to call rest services to retrieve data. For this, I want to create my objects in services (cache) and to use these services to display objects crud.

I would use CacheFactory in services, and for each crud operation, directly manipulate the array of objects in the cache.

Now I have the following code:

Cache service:

```
services.factory('TeacherCache', ['$cacheFactory', function ($cacheFactory) {
var cache = $cacheFactory('TeacherCache');
cache.put('teachers', [
    {
        id: 1,
        clientId: 100,
        username: 'teacher465462@gmail.com',
        password: 'mdp',
        lastName: 'THETEACHER2',
        firstName: 'DE',
        secondFirstName: '',
        address: '9, ADRESS',
        city: 'Paris',
        country: 'USA',
        zipCode: '7ffd5445020',
        email: 'my.email@gmail.com',
        homePhone: '006546546546',
        cellPhone: '54415151661',
        birthDate: '31/12/1958',
        enabled: true,
        roles: [
            {id: 1, name: 'Teacher'}
        ],
        //---------------------
        substitute: false,
        schoolClasses: [],
        subjects: [],
        options: [],
        employedDate: '28/08/2013'
    }
]);

return cache;
}]);
```

And my object service :

```
services.factory('TeacherService', 'TeacherCache', function (TeacherCache) {
return {
    errorMessage: '',
    create: [...],

    get: function (id) {
        [...]
    },

    //Get a list of db objects with query
    query: function () {
        return TeacherCache.get('teachers');
    },

    delete: [...]
};
})
;
```

But when i inject TeacherService in my controller and call query :

```
var teachers = TeacherService.query();
```

i have the following error :

```
Error: Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string
```

How can i resolve this ? thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second param in your 'TeacherService' should be an array.

```
controllers.factory('TeacherService', ['TeacherCache', function(TeacherCache){
    return {...}
}]);
```

Hope that helps, here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Qz1XKoJwCJFdZk0Q8Xo) with it working.